# Creating a dictionary of Func

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dictionary

I have a method which writes a `DataGridView` into a text file:

```
private void textToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
  saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
  saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
  saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
  saveFileDialog1.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm") + "_icmquery_" + GetTabName() + ".txt";
  if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  { 
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
      switch (mainTabGroup.SelectedTab.Name.ToString())
      {
        case "findScriptsTab":
          WriteTextFile(fs, findScriptsDataGrid);
          break;
        case "dialNumberAuditTab":
          WriteTextFile(fs, findScriptsDataGrid);
          break;
        case "calltypeRequalificationTab":
          WriteTextFile(fs, ctrDataGrid);
          break;
        case "targetAuditTab":
          WriteTextFile(fs, targetAuditDataGrid);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
public void WriteTextFile(FileStream fs, DataGridView dataGrid)
{
  using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
  {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
    {
      string line = string.Empty;
      foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
      {
        line = line + cell.Value + ",";
      }
      line = line.TrimEnd(',');
      tw.WriteLine(line);
    }
  }
}
```

But instead of using the large switch statement in `textToolStripMenuItem_Click()` I would like to define a dictionary in my form.  I have tried:

```
private Dictionary<TabPage, Func<FileStream, DataGridView>> WriteTextFileByTab(FileStream fs) = new Dictionary<TabPage, Func<FileStream, DataGridView>>()
{
  {findScriptsTab, WriteTextFile(fs, findScriptsDataGrid)}
};
```

But visual studios won't even register this as a valid thing. I typed this in manually but none of the intense would fill anything in. When I hover over "findScriptsTab" it says its a field by used like a type, and WriteTextFile says the same thing.  Any idea on how I could properly convert the switch statement to a dictionary so I can just say: `WriteTextFileByTab[mainTabGroup.SelectedTab];`?

Comment: That isn't a valid thing... It looks like you are trying to write a method but using the wrong syntax. Or you are using the keyword private inside another method when you shouldn't be. Check your syntax and if you can't spot the mistake clarify where that block of code is (ie inside a method or just inside the class).

Comment: All of this live inside of a form class.

Comment: You can definitely do this - I have done something similar in the past. One observation is you have defined your dictionary as `Dictionary<TabPage, Func<FileStream, DataGridView>>` - however, `WriteTextFile` returns void so you'd need an `Action` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define the parameter to the method for each item in the dictionary before you define the dictionary itself.  You need to declare the parameter's identifier when constructing each value of the dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<TabPage, Func<FileStream, DataGridView>> WriteTextFileByTab 
    = new Dictionary<TabPage, Func<FileStream, DataGridView>>()
{
    {findScriptsTab, fs =>  WriteTextFile(fs, findScriptsDataGrid)}
};
```

Of course if `findScriptsTab` and `findScriptsDataGrid` are instance fields, as I suspect that they are, you won't be able to use them when initializing another instance field.  As such, you'll need to initialize this dictionary in the constructor, not when declaring it.

It also looks like the delegates in your dictionary (based on your implementation of `WriteTextFile`) don't actually need to return a `DataGridView` so the appropriate delegate to use is actually an `Action<FileStream>`, not a `Func<FileStream, DataGridView>`.

Comment: I read. I ended up solving it by wrapping it in a method that returns a dictionary and then I use a LINQ query to call it out `WriteTextFileByTab(fs).FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Key == mainTabGroup.SelectedTab).Value();`

Comment: @aaronmallen That's a very poor way of designing the program.  As I said, you should simply initialize the dictionary in your constructor.  (If you want to encapsulate that into a method, that's just fine.)  You souldn't be creating the dictionary over again every single time you want to fetch a value.  Next, you shouldn't use `FirstOrDefault` to get the value of a dictionary from it's key.  The whole *point* of a `Dictionary` is to be able to efficiently look up a value given a key.  You do this using it's indexer.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to better illustrate this? show me how you would do it wrapped in a form class called Main().

Comment: @aaronmallen You don't know how to assign the dictionary that is created to a variable inside of your constructor?  You don't know how to use the indexer of a dictionary to get it's value?  Which of these are you having problems with?

Comment: I do not know how to assign the dictionary that is created to a variable inside of my constructor.

Comment: @aaronmallen Inside of your constructor you write `WriteTextFileByTab = new Dictionary<TabPage, Func<FileStream, DataGridView>>() { ... }`.  When declaring the dictionary replace the `=` operator and everything after it with a single `;`.

Comment: So then how do I populate the dictionary values?

Comment: @aaronmallen You populate it in the constructor, when initializing it.  The `...` is where you populate the values.

Comment: And then how do I pass the filestream to the dictionary?

Comment: @aaronmallen You never do, just like I told you earlier.  The dictionary never needs to be given the stream.  The dictionary takes a tab and gives you an action.  The action is what needs to be given a stream.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your meaning. Firstly we've already decided I should be using `Action<FileStream>` not `Func<FileStream>` so lets cut `Func` out of the equation. Now assuming findScriptsTab is a `TabPage` type can you edit your answer to reflect the comments.

Comment: @aaronmallen You have a `Dictionary<TabPage, Action<FileStream>>`.  You want to get an `Action<FileStream>` when you have a `TabPage`.  You use the dictionary's indexer to do that.  When you have the action, you give the action your `FileStream` and it does the appropriate actions with that stream.  If you don't know how to do either of those two things then spend some time looking up example usage of each of those types, because that's something that you need to learn how to do if you want to be using this solution.

Comment: `private Dictionary<TabPage, Action> WriteTextFileByTab(FileStream fs)
        {
            Dictionary<TabPage, Action> dictionary = new Dictionary<TabPage, Action>
            {
                {findScriptsTab, () => WriteTextFile(fs, findScriptsDataGrid)},
                {dialNumberAuditTab, () => WriteTextFile(fs, dnaDataGrid)},
                {calltypeRequalificationTab, () => WriteTextFile(fs, ctrDataGrid)},
                {targetAuditTab, () => WriteTextFile(fs, targetAuditDataGrid)}
            };
            return dictionary;
        }`

Comment: @aaronmallen You keep adding `(FileStream fs)` to the end of your dictionary name when I told you not to.  You add the type of the dictionary when initializing it in the constructor when you shouldn't, as I showed you.  You also are also providing no parameters to your methods inside of the dictionary, contrary to the whole point of this answer.  At this point it seems like you're not paying attention to what I'm telling you at all.  I've told you everything that you need to know to solve this problem (2 or three times).  Anytime you have another question, just read the answer again.

Comment: That's just it you haven't showed me, I've asked you repeatedly to edit your answer to reflect the comments so I can actually see the code that reflects what you are telling me to do.

Comment: @aaronmallen I showed you each piece of the puzzle.  All you had to do was put them together.  Instead you're sticking all sorts of completely unrelated pieces inbetween them.  I'm not going to just give you one big piece of code that you can copy-paste without reading.  It looks like that's what you did to get here, since apparently you don't understand the code that you started with at all.  You need to take the time to actually understand what each piece is doing, or you'll just create more and more problems down the road.

Comment: No but if I could actually see the code I could see what the heck your talking about.  Am I suppose to declare the Dictionary `Dictionary<TabPage,Action<FileStream,DataGridView>> WriteTextFile();` and then declare it again inside of that declaration? What constructor am I declaring this in?

Comment: This is what I am getting from what you are saying: `private Dictionary<TabPage, Action<FileStream>> WriteTextFileByTab()
        {
            return new Dictionary<TabPage, Action<FileStream>>
            {
                {findScriptsTab, fs  => WriteTextFile(fs, findScriptsDataGrid)},
                {dialNumberAuditTab, fs => WriteTextFile(fs, dnaDataGrid)},
                {calltypeRequalificationTab, fs => WriteTextFile(fs, ctrDataGrid)},
                {targetAuditTab, fs => WriteTextFile(fs, targetAuditDataGrid)}
            };
        }`

Comment: @aaronmallen You're close, but that's not quite right.  You declare a dictionary using: `private Dictionary<TabPage, Action<FileStream>> WriteTextFile;`  There is no parenthesis, and you have actions that only accept a `FileStream`.  You *don't* declare it again in the constructor, you *initialize* it by assigning a value to the dictionary that you *declared* earlier, without ever assigning a value to it.  It goes in the constructor of whatever object the dictionary is a field of.

Comment: if I have actions that only except filestream theres no point to the dictionary? every one would just be "KeyValue", fs => WriteTextFile(fs) wouldn't it? The whole point is to tell it which datagrid to write in the first place. FileStream is always the same value.

Comment: @aaronmallen The action in each value of the dictionary uses a different data grid.  The alternate design would be to just have a dictionary mapping tabs to data grids, assuming you are only ever going to call `WriteTextFile` on that grid.  It cleans up the code a bit, but not hugely.

Comment: so something like `Dictionary<TabPage, DataGridView> GetDataGridByTab; GetDataGridByTab = new Dictionary<TabPage, DataGridView>()                  {{findScriptsTab, findScriptsDataGrid}, //... };` in the actual button_click method?

Comment: @aaronmallen That's a viable alternative, yes, although just as with the earlier option you would want to declare the dictionary as a field, and initialize it in the constructor.  You should not re-create the dictionary every single time you want to use it.

Comment: In the constructor of the form? So would I give the dictionary a value in say Form_Load()?

Comment: @aaronmallen You could use the load event instead of the constructor if you wanted.  Either would work.  Forms have constructors too though.

Comment: @Servy awesome that's what I wasn't clear on so just define the dictionary value in `Main() {}` assuming the form name is Main.